# Tailwind, remove some duplicate classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using a package with a component that have tailwind on it, and I have to import the `app.css` from this package for correctly display.

And I'm using Tailwind on my project too, both have PurgeCSS, but if I run as production and I check my new `app.css` I notice a lot of duplicates classes.

In my app.css I have the next code:

```
@import "package-name/dist/app.css";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have to do something for remove duplicate classes?

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned you are using a package that includes Tailwind. What package is that?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use JIT. Enable just-in-time mode set the mode option to 'jit' in your tailwind.config.js.

please refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode